# Error undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass // Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running some issue here, i built a simple marketplace but when it comes to add a product in a cart, a line_item (representing a product by the ID) should be added to the cart. Instead no line_item is created and i have this error popping up.

I checked the relation between models, did the routes again, checked the views and forms. If i use @line_item.save instead of @line_item.save! i can see my cart view but no line_item has been created...

What am i missing here ? Thanks

```
  create_table "line_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.integer "cart_id"
    t.integer "order_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :order, optional: true

  def total_price
    self.quantity * self.product.price
  end
end
```

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Find associated product and current cart
    chosen_product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    current_cart = @current_cart

    # If cart already has this product then find the relevant line_item and iterate quantity otherwise create a new line_item for this product
    if current_cart.products.include?(chosen_product)
      # Find the line_item with the chosen_product
      @line_item = current_cart.line_items.find_by(product_id: chosen_product)
      # Iterate the line_item's quantity by one

      @line_item.quantity += 1

    else
      @line_item = LineItem.new
      @line_item.cart = current_cart
      @line_item.product = chosen_product

    end

    # Save and redirect to cart show path
    @line_item.save!
    redirect_to cart_path(current_cart)

  end

  def add_quantity
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    @line_item.quantity += 1
    @line_item.save
    redirect_to cart_path(@current_cart)
  end

  def reduce_quantity
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    if @line_item.quantity > 1
      @line_item.quantity -= 1
    end
    @line_item.save
    redirect_to cart_path(@current_cart)
  end

  def destroy
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    @line_item.destroy
    redirect_to cart_path(@current_cart)
  end

  private

  def line_item_params
    params.require(:line_item).permit(:quantity,:product_id, :cart_id)
  end

end
```

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

root 'products#index'

get 'carts/:id' => "carts#show", as: "cart"
delete 'carts/:id' => "carts#destroy"

post 'line_items/:id/add' => "line_items#add_quantity", as: "line_item_add"
post 'line_items/:id/reduce' => "line_items#reduce_quantity", as: "line_item_reduce"
post 'line_items' => "line_items#create"
get 'line_items/:id' => "line_items#show", as: "line_item"
delete 'line_items/:id' => "line_items#destroy"

resources :products
resources :orders

end
```

Comment: Does `LineItem.new` initialize with a `quantity = 1`? Or is `quantity = nil` for new line items?

Answer (score 2):

Your `quantity` is nil, that's why you get the error. Maybe add a default value for it in the migration like so:

```
t.quantity, type: :integer, null: false, default: 0
```

Edit: added `null: false` since it's a good idea, credits to top comment bellow.

Comment: Including `null: false` would also be a good idea.

Comment: Alternatively, some people prefer a `NOT NULL` constraint (`null: false` in Rails) _without_ a default. It's a bit stricter than having a default, forcing the application to explicitly specify the quantity.